# Temporal on ECS

Tags: amazon-ecs, temporal-workflow

I am trying to figure out how to deploy temporal in ECS.
There are materials available, how to do it in EKS using helm.
Looking forward to any material guidance on temporal deployment using ECS fargate.

Comment: even I am looking for the same 

Answer (score 2):

Temporal doesn't currently have an ECS guide (see https://docs.temporal.io/docs/server/production-deployment/#external-runbooks), but you can try:

https://github.com/Progymedia/temporalio-cluster-cdk

Answer (score 1):

We faced a similar problem a while back when we wanted to get temporal running on ECS.

Having found nothing that worked as we wanted, we built a small tool that uses AWS copilot under the hood and deploys an entire temporal cluster with just a single command.

You can check it out and see if it suits your use case

https://github.com/wednesday-solutions/temporal-ecs